Hint for parametrizing a surface that is equidistant from a plane through the origin and a point not on it
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$
This is for homework, so please only hints and light nudges!
Problem:
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane through the origin with normal vector $\vec{n}=(a,b, c)$ and if $F = (x_F, y_F, z_F)$ be a point not on $P$. Let $S$ be the set of points $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the distance $FM$ is equal to the distance between $M$ and the plane $P$. Find a parametrization for the surface $S$.
Start of my solution:
The distance $FM$ from the point $F$ to the point $M=(x_M,y_M,z_M)$ is
$$FM = \norm{F-M} = \sqrt{(x_F-x_M)^2+(y_F-y_M)^2+(z_F-z_M)^2}$$
The plane $\mathcal{P}$ with normal vector $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ passing through the origin is the set of all points $\vec{p} = (x,y,z)$ such that $\vec{n} \cdot \vec{p} = 0$ i.e. $ax+by+cz=0$. The distance between $M$ and the plane $P$ is given by the distance between $M$ and its orthogonal projection, $I-\vec{u}\vec{u}^T$, onto the plane $P$:
$$\operatorname{dist}(M, \mathcal{P}):=\norm{M-(I-\vec{u}\vec{u}^T)M}=\norm{\vec{u}\vec{u}^T M},$$
where $\vec{u} = \vec{n}/\norm{\vec{n}}$ is the unit normal vector to the plane $\mathcal{P}$. So,
$$\vec{u}\vec{u}^T M = \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\begin{bmatrix}
  a^2 & ab & ac\\
  ab & b^2 & bc\\
  ac & bc & c^2
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 x_M\\
 y_M\\
 z_M
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2} \begin{bmatrix}
 a^2 x_M + ab y_M + ac z_M\\
 ab x_M +b^2 y_M + bc z_M\\
 ac x_M+ bc y_M + c^2 z_M
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \left(ax_M \vec{u} + b y_M \vec{u}+ c z_M \vec{u}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\left(ax_M+b y_M + c z_M\right) \vec{u}.$$
Since $\norm{\vec{u}}=1$, it follows that the distance between the point $M$ and the plane $\mathcal{P}$ through the origin is given by
$$\operatorname{dist}(M, \mathcal{P})= \frac{|a x_M + b y_M + c z_M|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
Thus, the set $S$ of points $M = (x_M, y_M, z_M)$ must satisfy
$$(x_F-x_M)^2+(y_F-y_M)^2+(z_F-z_M)^2 = \frac{(a x_M + b y_M + c z_M)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
My confusion:
So here is where I am stuck--I do not recognize this last equation as the implicit equation of any well-known surfaces. On my first attempt at expanding everything and grouping the components of $M$ did not yield any thing recognizable either--though I may have had an algebraic blunder, so I will retry in a little bit after a break.
If anyone could give me a little hint or nudge in the right direction (or if there is a better approach!).

Did you consider the behaviour of level sets /sketched them?  I haven't checked through the solution that you wrote ,just the final equation as a disclaimer. Maybe it won't give it away, but I'm sure it could possibly help as a general approach.

@J.Dmaths I did a contour plot using mathematica and I guess it is a paraboloid but I'm failing to see this algebraically.

A parabola at every point is equidistant to a point and a line. Spin the line and parabola about the axis and you have your problem.

@RobinSparrow Ah right, of course! I am embarrassed because we actually did that problem months ago... Anyway, If you want to post that as an answer, I would accept it.

A parabola is at every point equidistant from a line and a point. Spin the line and parabola about the axis and you have your problem.
